While applying Kustomization to Kubernetes cluster getting "error: no objects passed to apply"
I am trying to change version of the deployment using Kustomization, so that i dont have to change the original deployment file, but when I apply the Kustomization.yaml file I am getting "error: no objects passed to apply" error.
my Deployment file is as follows:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: booking

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: booking-deployment
  namespace: booking
  labels:
    app: booking-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: booking-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: booking-app
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: booking-pod
         image: <image>0.0.1
         ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
         env:
          - name: databse_url
            value: <db_url>
          - name: databse_username
            value: <db_username>
          - name: databse_password
            value: <db_password>

and my Kustomization.yaml file is as follows:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: booking-deployment
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0
        value:
          name: coupon_service_url
          value: <url_to_coupon_service>

images:
- name: <image>
  newName: docker.io/<username>/<image>
  newTag: 0.0.9

when I run kubectl apply -k . I get error: no objects passed to apply and when I run kubectl kustomize . I don't get any error, but the image version does not change in the pod.
What am I doing wrong here?
Edit:
As some other question on stackoverflow suggested that i should add deployment.yaml as resources in the kustomization file, I added that as well and tried, it did apply the deployment.yaml but the version it picked up was from deployment.yaml file and not the one mentioned in kustomization file

Does this answer your question? Changing image tags and name with kustomization.yaml

You forgot to specify the resources in your kustomization file

@Paolo this does not answer my question, When I added resources, it applied the original deployment file and did not change the image.

It does answer your question: the reason you are getting the "no objects passed to apply" error is because you have no resources section in your kustomization.yaml. I'm voting to close as "caused by a typo". If you are in fact asking something else, then update the question to include a functional kustomization.yaml and a description of the actual problem.

Sorry my bad, its working as expected now with the fix suggested, i dont know what happened the other day.
